# Is a 600 lb. deadlift possible at 160?

Tags: strength-training, deadlifts, powerlifting, genetics

My goal is to hit 600 lbs. RAW on a deadlift -- no straps, belts, suits, or steroids.

I am currently 160 and do not plan to gain anymore weight. My max dead is 315 lbs. now.

I would need to almost double my deadlift without gaining a single pound.

I plan to do this within 3 years. Is this possible without drugs or gaining weight?

Or maybe if I were to gain more (muscle) weight, I could then lose more fat and break even.

This would be incredible as I'd be outlifting most guys on the gear if I could do this.

Breakdown:

5'10"

160 lbs.

Bodyfat: 14.7%

Fat mass: 22.4 lbs.

Pure muscle weight: 79 lbs.

Skeleton weight: 23 lbs.

Organ weight/etc.: ~20 lbs.

Water/etc. weight: ~16 lbs.

Comment: I am wondering why you want to achieve this deadlift goal with the constraint of not changing weight class?

Answer (score 2):

To get some idea as to the maximum you will be able to lift while being drug tested and maintaining 74kg (closes category to 160lbs) we can look to the IPF ([International Powerlifting Federation) records](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/championships/records.html). They perform checks for the main anabolics but I suspect they potentially aren't a rigorous as the International Olympic Committee. Unfortunately powerlifting is not an Olympic sport.

There are a few records of interest, you are looking for 600lbs which is just over a 6 plate deadlift (272kg):

```
Date       Weight(kg)  Name                Country   Birth year  Bodyweight (kg)
07.05.15   327.5       GAISHINETC Sergei   RUS       1986        72.59
04.11.14   325.0       GAISHINETC Sergei   RUS       1986        73.16
04.11.14   323.0       GORIACHOK Anatolii  UKR       1979        73.54 
01.01.11   320.0       World Standard
```

The world standard is 320kg (705lbs) and these are equipped (belted).

So technically, yes. Based on the information provided you can achieve a 600lb deadlift at your bodyweight without the use of steroids.

As a general rule of thumb, you need to 'eat big' to 'lift big', a large calorie surplus will significantly help you progress your strength rapidly. 3 years to double your deadlift without eating at a surplus is very difficult and most of the people in this weight class weigh more and then cut before competition to hit their weight class.

Comment: Just to note, OP said no belt. "Raw" in IPF still allows belt.

Comment: Ass DeeV says. "Equipped" means something else, having a deadlift suit. I'm not going to argue this point, but I personally do not believe that IPF power-lifting is anywhere close to 'clean' and the compettors are of course genetically atypical regardless. The OP should do their own research around that to understand the context of these numbers. The OP might want to [chart their intended wilkes score](http://ironstrong.org/topic/1042-strength-standards-beginner-intermediate-advanced/) to understand their numbers in terms of normal people.

Answer (score 0):

I am a very similar case. My height is 5'10 and I weigh 165 lbs (75kg).

You can find all the world records [here](http://www.powerliftingwatch.com/records/raw/world), tested and untested. 
This guy Kjell Egill Bakkelund holds it with 716lbs (325kg) @165 lbs.
You can see him doing 320kg for 5 [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD-UuLuRYcg).

You can find a few guys here and there pulling over 700 at this weight such as Paul Nguyen (717@165 and 740@167) BUT, you will notice that these guys are shorter than you. This considerably shortens the range of motion and makes it easier for them to pull.

At 5'10 and 160-165 lbs, you and I are probably not likely to go for world records, at least not in this weight class.

However I do believe 600 at our height and weight is achievable.
I pulled 315 a little over two years ago. I can now pull 500 without a belt or straps. And I'm still seeing progress and definitely think 600 is achievable.

One important thing to consider is genetics. Some people progress faster and further. The majority will never pull 700 at such bodyweights. But 600 seems achievable for most young people.

Less than 3 years is possible too. Your programming, eating habits, sleep and overall stress levels are the biggest factors. A big thing is do not get injured because this will harm your progress and set you off for some time. Slow and steady. Form first.

Also your age will impact a lot. I assume you are in your 20's so this shouldn't be a problem.

Best of luck !